# Assets are not loaded when deploy app to shared hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, web-deployment, symfony-3.4

I installed the symfony app to the shared server. The root of the project is

```
/public_html/back/symfony
```

I put in directory '/public_html/back/symfony' the .htaccess like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

when I try to acces the page in the browser assets are not loaded and I get the error :

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://api.mydomain.com/build/js/app/base-script.62abfcbd.js”.
```

Have you an idea about that ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have share all the points of deploying a Symfony project ? like clear cache
[Deploy in Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html)

Here you can see how to prepare and use the deploy asset: 
[Deploy Asset in Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html#how-do-i-deploy-my-encore-assets)

Symfony advise this for assets :

- Building and minifying your assets with Webpack Encore
- Pushing assets to a CDN

Hope it will help